# Como subir varios archivos mediante el modelo Django

Tags: django-models

específicamente aquí....... mediante este campo solo me deja cargar 1 archivo
y yo necesito cargar varios.

```
ArchivoDocument = models.FileField(verbose_name= "Croquis",upload_to='documentacion', null=True , blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un modelo que contenga los demás datos que necesites al respecto

```
class Archivador(models.Model):
    campo1....
    campo2....
```

Y luego crear otro modelo donde se carga el archivo y se relaciona con el ´Archivador´

```
class Documento(models.Model):
    archivador = models.ForeignKey(Archivador, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='archivador', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    archivo_document = models.FileField(verbose_name= "Croquis",upload_to='documentacion', null=True , blank=True)
```

Con esta estructura puedes implementar un inline en el administrador